# How do I login using ftp on linux

Tags: linux, authentication, ftp

The webhost I use logs me out if there is 3 minutes of inactivity. I created a simple script to save me typing to server address everytime which is...

```
ftp www.mywebsite.com
```

But what I really want is for the script to log me in so I can start sending commands! When I searched the only solution I found was

```
ftp: ftp://username:password@www.mywebsite.com
```

But this just returns

```
ftp: ftp://username:password@www.mywebsite.com: System error
ftp>
```

I'm using linux mint 15

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understood. Why not use Filezilla and send an automatic keep-alive command (found under Settings -> Connection -> FTP)

Comment: Filezilla does what I want but i really want a command line tool...When i run the command 'filezilla ftp://user:pass@web.com' it logs me in but when I replace 'filezilla' with 'ftp' I get an error...